# Showing a row that doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, outer-join

I have a select that fetches some data for me. 
I'm trying to make a query that shows me that data but if it doesn't exist it will show me the first 5 columns with data that I provided. Here is the query

```
  DECLARE @miesiac INT = 1
  DECLARE @opis VARCHAR(30) = '';
  WITH  cte
          AS ( SELECT  DISTINCT
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY emp_name,
                                         doc_documentdate ORDER BY doc_documentdate ) s
                       ,emp_name Kod
                       ,emp_id id
                       ,Emp_Surname Nazwisko
                       ,Emp_FirstName Imie
                       ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Doc_DocumentDate, 120), '') Data
                       ,CASE WHEN doc_documentdate = ttc_date
                                  AND ttc_isholiday = 0 THEN 'S'
                             WHEN doc_documentdate = ttc_date
                                  AND ttc_isholiday = 6
                                  OR ttc_isholiday = 7
                                  OR ELM_DecimalColumn1 = 0 THEN 'W'
                             WHEN ELM_DecimalColumn1 IS NULL THEN 'w'
                             ELSE 'P'
                        END Typdnia
                       ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), elm_datecolumn1, 108),
                               '00:00:00') GodzOd
                       ,ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), elm_datecolumn2, 108),
                               '00:00:00') GodzDo
                       ,CASE WHEN ELM_decimalcolumn1 > 0
                             THEN 'praca podstawowa'
                             ELSE 'brak'
                        END Strefa
                       ,@opis Opis
                       ,ISNULL(emp_shortstringcolumn2, 'brak') Wydzial
                       ,ISNULL(ELM_ShortStringColumn5, '0') Wydzial_adres_wezla
                       ,ISNULL(a.dic_svalue, ' brak') Projekt
                       ,ISNULL(b.DIC_ShortStringColumn1, '1') Projekt_adres_wezla
               FROM     Employees
                        LEFT JOIN elements ON emp_id = ELM_EmpID
                                              AND ELM_FflID = 200
                        LEFT JOIN documents ON elm_objectid = doc_id
                                               AND Doc_DdfID = 2
                        LEFT JOIN dictionaries a ON ELM_IntColumn2 = a.DIC_ID
                        LEFT JOIN Dictionaries b ON elm_intcolumn2 = b.DIC_ID
                        LEFT JOIN ttscalendar ON ttc_date = Doc_DocumentDate
                        RIGHT JOIN dim_timeday ON doc_documentdate = tmd_fulldatekey
             )
    SELECT  ISNULL(cte1.kod, '') Kod
           ,ISNULL(cte1.nazwisko, '') Nazwisko
           ,ISNULL(cte1.imie, '') Imie
           ,ISNULL(cte1.data, '') Data
           ,ISNULL(cte1.TypDnia, '') Typdnia
           ,ISNULL(cte1.GodzOd, '00:00') W1_GodzOd
           ,ISNULL(cte1.godzdo, '00:00') W1_GodzDo
           ,ISNULL(cte1.strefa, 'brak') W1_Strefa
           ,ISNULL(cte1.opis, '') W1_Opis
           ,ISNULL(cte1.wydzial, 'brak') W1_Wydzial
           ,ISNULL(cte1.wydzial_adres_wezla, '0') W1_Wydzial_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte1.Projekt, 'brak') W1_Projekt
           ,ISNULL(cte1.Projekt_adres_wezla, '1') W1_Projekt_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte2.GodzOd, '') W2_GodzOd
           ,ISNULL(cte2.godzdo, '') W2_GodzDo
           ,ISNULL(cte2.strefa, '') W2_Strefa
           ,ISNULL(cte2.opis, '') W2_Opis
           ,ISNULL(cte2.wydzial, '') W2_Wydzial
           ,ISNULL(cte2.wydzial_adres_wezla, '') W2_Wydzial_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte2.Projekt, '') W2_Projekt
           ,ISNULL(cte2.Projekt_adres_wezla, '') W2_Projekt_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte3.GodzOd, '') W3_GodzOd
           ,ISNULL(cte3.godzdo, '') W3_GodzDo
           ,ISNULL(cte3.strefa, '') W3_Strefa
           ,ISNULL(cte3.opis, '') W3_Opis
           ,ISNULL(cte3.wydzial, '') W3_Wydzial
           ,ISNULL(cte3.wydzial_adres_wezla, '') W3_Wydzial_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte3.Projekt, '') W3_Projekt
           ,ISNULL(cte3.Projekt_adres_wezla, '') W3_Projekt_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte4.GodzOd, '') W4_GodzOd
           ,ISNULL(cte4.godzdo, '') W4_GodzDo
           ,ISNULL(cte4.strefa, '') W4_Strefa
           ,ISNULL(cte4.opis, '') W4_Opis
           ,ISNULL(cte4.wydzial, '') W4_Wydzial
           ,ISNULL(cte4.wydzial_adres_wezla, '') W4_Wydzial_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte4.Projekt, '') W4_Projekt
           ,ISNULL(cte4.Projekt_adres_wezla, '') W4_Projekt_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte5.GodzOd, '') W5_GodzOd
           ,ISNULL(cte5.godzdo, '') W5_GodzDo
           ,ISNULL(cte5.strefa, '') W5_Strefa
           ,ISNULL(cte5.opis, '') W5_Opis
           ,ISNULL(cte5.wydzial, '') W5_Wydzial
           ,ISNULL(cte5.wydzial_adres_wezla, '') W5_Wydzial_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte5.Projekt, '') W5_Projekt
           ,ISNULL(cte5.Projekt_adres_wezla, '') W5_Projekt_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte6.GodzOd, '') W6_GodzOd
           ,ISNULL(cte6.godzdo, '') W6_GodzDo
           ,ISNULL(cte6.strefa, '') W6_Strefa
           ,ISNULL(cte6.opis, '') W6_Opis
           ,ISNULL(cte6.wydzial, '') W6_Wydzial
           ,ISNULL(cte6.wydzial_adres_wezla, '') W6_Wydzial_adres_wezla
           ,ISNULL(cte6.Projekt, '') W6_Projekt
           ,ISNULL(cte6.Projekt_adres_wezla, '') W6_Projekt_adres_wezla
    FROM    cte cte1
            LEFT JOIN cte cte2 ON cte1.Kod = cte2.kod
                                  AND cte1.data = cte2.data
                                  AND cte2.s = 2
            LEFT JOIN cte cte3 ON cte2.Kod = cte3.kod
                                  AND cte2.data = cte3.data
                                  AND cte3.s = 3
            LEFT JOIN cte cte4 ON cte3.Kod = cte4.kod
                                  AND cte3.data = cte4.data
                                  AND cte4.s = 4
            LEFT JOIN cte cte5 ON cte4.Kod = cte5.kod
                                  AND cte4.data = cte5.data
                                  AND cte5.s = 5
            LEFT JOIN cte cte6 ON cte5.Kod = cte6.kod
                                  AND cte5.data = cte6.data
                                  AND cte6.s = 6
    WHERE   cte1.s = 1
            AND MONTH(cte1.data) = @Miesiac
            AND cte1.id = 7
    ORDER BY cte1.data
           ,cte1.kod
```

Here is the data

```
 ANJO_141   ANTONKIEWICZ    JOLANTA 2016-01-22  S   00:00:00    00:00:00    brak        NF  1.8  brak   1
ANJO_141    ANTONKIEWICZ    JOLANTA 2016-01-23  W   07:00:00    12:00:00    praca podstawowa        NF  1.8  brak   1
ANJO_141    ANTONKIEWICZ    JOLANTA 2016-01-27  P   07:00:00    15:00:00    praca podstawowa        NF  1.8  brak   1
ANJO_141    ANTONKIEWICZ    JOLANTA 2016-01-28  W   00:00:00    00:00:00    brak        NF  1.8  brak   1
```

Comment: Hello Michal, welcome to stackoverflow! For other users to help you you'll probably need to provide us with some more information on what you're trying to achieve, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: Ass you see data i provided ,i recive some information that is inside table elements. It is about working time. Now i wanna show that if someone is nut putted in elements for specific day i want to select his emp_name,emp_firstname,emp_surname, date and rest of columns should be empty.